# Extend GWT application with Angular

Tags: angular

What we have: an application built with GWT, it is single page, "tree on the left", "tabs on the right".

What we need: We would love to extend it using Angular.

Question: Is it possible to embed Angular elements to a few places of our app, also note "multi-tabs" nature, so many documents can be opened at once and each document can have its own plugins configuration?

PS: Seems it might be an answer [Angular and GWT in perfect harmony](https://github.com/bitwerk/AngularGwtExample)

[image: GWT app appearance]

Comment: Try looking up GWT JsInterop.

Comment: Thank you, will do